# How to assign value to a final variable

Tags: java, android, final

the variable "startTs" needs to be declared as final. and when I declare it as final android studio highlights it and says "cant assign value to final variable"
and if removed the final modifier i receive "variable must be final"

now i want to use the variable "startTs" and assign value to it,how to do that

please let me know how to fix this

**code**:

```
final long startTs;

        mbtnLogFileAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (action) {
                    case "Record":
                        Log.i(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("ATRx.onPreExecute", "start Recording logs"));

                        mbtnLogFileAction.setText("Pause");
                        metLogFileName.setEnabled(false);

                        String logFileName = metLogFileName.getText().toString();

                        if (logFileName != null && !logFileName.isEmpty()) {

                            if (!mLogFileHT.containsKey(logFileName)) {
                                startTs = TimeUtils.getTSSec();//cant assign value to final variable
                                mLogFileHT.put(logFileName, startTs);
                            } else {
                                startTs = mLogFileHT.get(logFileName);//cant assign value to final variable
                            }
```

Comment: @user2121 : Declare `startTs` at class level. :)

Comment: Why is it outside the `OnClickListener`? Where is it used? What is its lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put startTs globally.

```
public class YourClass
{


long startTs;

// your other code goes here..

        mbtnLogFileAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (action) {
                    case "Record":
                        Log.i(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("ATRx.onPreExecute", "start Recording logs"));

                        mbtnLogFileAction.setText("Pause");
                        metLogFileName.setEnabled(false);

                        String logFileName = metLogFileName.getText().toString();

                        if (logFileName != null && !logFileName.isEmpty()) {

                            if (!mLogFileHT.containsKey(logFileName)) {
                                startTs = TimeUtils.getTSSec();//cant assign value to final variable
                                mLogFileHT.put(logFileName, startTs);
                            } else {
                                startTs = mLogFileHT.get(logFileName);//cant assign value to final variable
                            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using an anonymous inner class ,`startTs` has to final to be used inside it and since it's final ,it should be a compile time constant and can't be reassigned

Answer (score 0):

Final member variable must be initialized at the time of declaration or inside constructor, failure to do so will result in compilation error.